# How to implement unsafePartsOf using lens

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I'm trying to implement a simple version of `unsafePartsOf` with the specialized signature:

```
unsafePartsOf :: Traversal s t a b -> Lens s t [a] [b]
```

After trying to understand how it works, I come up with this ([repl](https://repl.it/@shouya/HarshDisguisedField#main.hs)).

```
myUnsafePartsOf :: Traversal s t a b -> Lens s t [a] [b]
myUnsafePartsOf traverse = lens getter setter
  where
    -- getter :: s -> [a]
    getter s = s ^.. traverse
    -- setter :: s -> [b] -> t
    setter s xs = evalState (s & traverse %%~ assignElem) xs
    assignElem _a = state $ \case
        [] -> error "list not long enough"
        (b : bs) -> (b, bs)
```

I think that using `lens :: (s -> a) -> (s -> b -> t) -> Lens s t a b` to separate the definition getter and setter will make them easier to understand.

However, this function doesn't type check because `^..` operator (`toListOf`) has a (specialized) signature of `toListOf :: Traversal' s a -> s -> [a]` where the original `s` and `t` (as well as `a` and `b`) would get unified.

I then tried to implement a more general version of `toListOf` ([the same repl](https://repl.it/@shouya/HarshDisguisedField#main.hs)) with the following code:

```
toListOf :: Traversal s t a b -> s -> [a]
toListOf traverse s = execState (traverse getElem s) []
  where getElem a = modify (a:)
```

but failed again because that would require to unify `b` with `()` due to the usage of `modify`. I understand that there is no way for me to create an arbitrary `b` in the `getElem` so this function is impossible.

Note that it's actually possible to define the safe `partsOf` using `lens` in a similar way:

```
myPartsOf :: Traversal' s a -> Lens' s [a]
myPartsOf t = lens getter setter
  where
    getter s = s ^.. t
    -- setter :: s -> [a] -> s
    setter s xs = evalState (s & t %%~ assignElem) xs
    assignElem a = state $ \case
        [] -> (a, [])
        (x : xs) -> (x, xs)
```

Is it possible to define `unsafePartsOf` using `lens`? If so how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the `getter` as:

```
getter s = s ^.. (\f -> Const . getConst . traverse (Const . getConst . f))
```

and it appears to typecheck.

Comment: That's a smart way to get rid of the phantom `b` unification by rewrapping with the Const!

Comment: A cute name for that pattern would be `reConst = Const . getConst`—it “reconstitutes” or “reconstructs” the wrapper. Of course, because the second type parameter of `Const` has role `phantom`, this is just a specialisation of `coerce`.